# C# inheritance and default constructors

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

Suppose there is a base class `A` and a class `B` derived from `A`.
Then, we know that the constructor of class `A` is never inherited by class `B`. However, when a new object of `B` is created, then - the default constructor of the class `A` is called prior to the default/custom constructor of class `B` is invoked. Maybe the purpose of this is that the fields of class `A` need to be initialized to default values.

Now, suppose that class `A` has defined a custom constructor. This means that the default constructor of class `A` is silently removed by the compiler. Now, on creating a new instance of class `B`, which constructor of class `A` is automatically called before invoking the class `B`'s constructor? (How does the class `A` fields get initialized in such a case?)

Comment: I didn't realize that OOPS was Object Oriented Programming S*. Not suggesting an edit because I like to think of it as ["oops"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/92181/136696).

Comment: Have rolled back the edit that removed the c# tag, and also edited the subject line for clarity. This is definitely a language-specific question.

Answer (score 65):

> Now, on creating a new instance of class `B`, which constructor of class `A` is automatically called before invoking the class `B` constructor?

The code will fail to compile, basically. Each constructor has to chain to another constructor, either implicitly or explicitly. The constructor it chains to can be in the same class (with `this`) or the base class (with `base`).

A constructor like this:

```
public B() {}
```

is implicitly:

```
public B() : base() {}
```

... and if you don't specify a constructor at all, it will be implicitly added in the same way - but it still has to have something to call. So for example, your scenario:

```
public class A
{
    public A(int x) {}
}

public class B : A {}
```

leads to a compiler error of:

> error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter `'x'` of `'A.A(int)'`

However, you can specify a different constructor call explicitly, e.g.

```
public B() : base(10) {} // Chain to base class constructor
```

or

```
public B() : this(10) {} // Chain to same class constructor, assuming one exists
```

Comment: Will specifying an explicit empty constructor in class A get rid of the error?

Comment: @helloworld: A parameterless one? Absolutely. The constructor you chain to doesn't have to be introduced implicitly by the compiler - it can be an ordinary parameterless one. Or it could even be one with just optional parameters, or just a `params` parameter. Basically, so long as `: base()` would work, it's fine.

Answer (score 6):

Once you provide your own constructor to `class A`, no automatic invocations happens during the `class B` object creation.

The first line in your `class B` constructor should be `super(paramsToClassAConstructor)` or it can be call to another  constructor with in the `class B` using `this()`. It is the responsibility of the second constructor in `class B` to call the `class A` constructor in such case.

Comment: What you wrote applies to Java, but the question is tagged as C# which has different rules.

Comment: Ho my goodness.. I did not have a look at tags..thanks for opening up my eyes :)

Answer (score 4):

When a constructor completes execution - the object is **in a valid initial state.** We are supposed to use objects which are valid.
    When we provide a non-default constructor for class A - we are effectively saying - to construct class A object i.e. to be in the valid initial state - we need more information - which is provided by the parameters.
    Given this, the compiler helps by **not** generating the default constructor. The client code will fail to compile (as it should - how else will we make the object land in a valid state?) - and the client programmer would have to sit up and take notice.
    When you provide an explicit empty constructor - you are effectively telling the compiler - I know what I am doing - the default constructor would most probably initialize the fields to some sensible default values.
 
    Or to promote reuse - the default constructor can call the non-default one with some default values.
 
    A subclass knows about its super class - a sub-class constructor can invoke super class methods - (some commonly reused methods in sub-classes). Given the above - this requires that the super class part should be in a **valid state - i.e. its constructor was executed prior to any of its method invocation**. This necessitates calling the super constructor before the sub-class constructor.
    Given this - you will easily be able to design your constructor to enforce the correct **initial state behavior**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special rule for defining base class parameter constructors. Rules are same as other class constructors. You can define number of constructor as follows:

```
class baseclass
    {
        public baseclass()
        {

        }
        public baseclass(string message)
        {

        }
    }
```

If base class has constructor then child class or derived class are required to call the constructor from its base class.

```
class childclass : baseclass
    {
        public childclass()
        {
        }
        public childclass(string message)
            : base(message)
        {            
        }
    }
```